# Spring SPNEGO without form

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spnego, spring-security-kerberos

I have some questions about setting up SPNEGO without use of form fall back.

I am writing a web service that uses SPNEGO authentication and returns a signed JWT for the authenticated principal. I don't have any use for forms (can't use forms with authentication-only principals, for example).

1. Can I skip the formLogin() and logout() parts as shown in the spring SPNEGO reference, and use the zero-argument SpnegoEntryPoint constructor?
2. It seems from looking at the [source for SPNEGO filter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-kerberos/blob/master/spring-security-kerberos-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/kerberos/web/authentication/SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java) that if the Authorization header is missing then the filter doesn't actually return a 401 Unauthorized response with a WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate challenge to the caller. That is, there is no `else` to the check on line 135. Am I reading this correctly? The RFC states

   > If the server receives a request for an access-protected object, and
   >   if an acceptable Authorization header has not been sent, the server
   >   responds with a "401 Unauthorized" status code, and a "WWW-
   >   Authenticate:" header
3. If the above is correct, are clients expected to preemptively send the Authorization header?

Thanks!

**EDIT (and probably RESOLVED)**: My original security config had:

```
http.exceptionHandling()
    .authenticationEntryPoint(spnegoEntryPoint())
    .and()
.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/v1/**").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
.addFilterBefore()...`
```

When I remove `.antMatchers("/v1/**").permitAll()` the SpnegoEntryPoint kicks in and I now see a 401 with WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate response.

Of course now I get a `Server not found in Kerberos database` gss_init_sec_context() failure but i suspect that has to do with SPN setup or host name resolution (since I am testing this locally on my Macbook) than the Spring app.

Will update once finally when I get this working.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, the zero argument cosntructor is correct.
2. The Filter is not responsible for setting the Status and Header. The SpnegoEntryPoint is. org.springframework.security.kerberos.web.authentication.SpnegoEntryPoint.commence(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, AuthenticationException)
3. No, see 2.

Comment: So, when does the entry point get invoked? Only upon an exception? I am trying to step through the entry point as well as filter and execution never hits the entry point upon a request.